# Documenting webservice API Reference guide?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, documentation, reference

Online webservice API/reference guide - What software application do you use to document your webservice/API technical specification/reference guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice solution is to build the documentation yourself using xml documentation comments and then creating web pages from the resulting xml.

**DIY**

[MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/z04awywx(v=vs.120).aspx) on using xml comments.

**Tools/Plugins**

There are a few libraries out there that make it simple for you to create documentation for your api.

[Atomineer](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) is very good and can create documentation in many different formats to meet your needs.

**Web API**

With [Web API documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-api-help-pages) is rolled into your project with a nice UI to expose it. This also uses xml documentation and you can add your own details to that which comes out of the box.

[Broken link, am trying to find it again.]
Heres a good blog post on this method [api documentaion](http://www.robertbeal.com/26/creating-api-documentation)

Answer (score 1):

I use a documentation generator called [TechWriter for Web Services](http://www.adivo.com/techwriter-for-web-services.aspx).  It's not that expensive and has saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

[IMHO Sandcastle works pretty nicely](http://shfb.codeplex.com/)
Free tool that uses existing xml documentation to produce .chm or .html files that look similar to msdn documentation.